# Loop through a JSON responseText array using the keys with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

Using Javascript. I'm trying to loop through an array encoded with JSON. Here is a sample of the array:

```
{"test1":"some info","test2":"more info","test3":"more stuff"}
```

Inside each loop I am checking to see if a DIV id exists with the name of the keys.

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
```

I'm using a for() loop, but I can't get it to work. If I remove the for() loop it works just fine if I search for only 1 DIV id.

```
for(var key in responseText)
```

Here is the script. Does anyone know how I can loop through the array from responseText using the array keys as the names of the DIV id's?

```
<script>
function loadInfo() {
  var req = new Request({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'getinfo.php,
    noCache: true,
    onRequest: function() {
      for (var key in responseText) {
        if (document.getElementById(key)) {
          $(key).set('html', 'Loading');
        }
      }
    },
    onComplete: function(responseText, responseHtml) {
      if (JSON.decode(responseText) != null) {
        var data = JSON.decode(responseText);
        for (var key in responseText) {
          if (document.getElementById(key)) {
            $(key).set('html', data[key]);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    onFailure: function() {
      for (var key in responseText) {
        if (document.getElementById(key)) {
          $(key).set('html', '-');
        }
      }
    }
  }).send();
}
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  loadInfo();
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode the JSON before you iterate over the keys. So, where you say:

```
for(var key in responseText) {
```

replace that with:

```
for(var key in data) {
```

assuming

```
 var data = JSON.decode(responseText);
```

Also, some of your callback functions don't specify `responseText` as a parameter. If you want to access this for each callback, you have to explicitly include `responseText` as a parameter. Example:

```
onRequest: function(){
```

should be:

```
onRequest: function(responseText){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using the wrong variable name.

```
var data = JSON.decode(responseText);

for(var key in responseText) {
```

Should read

```
var data = JSON.decode(responseText);

for(var key in data) {
```

Note that instead of `responseText` after `in`, it reads `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want `JSON.parse`? This would parse the JSON response into a javascript object that you can use the `for/in` against.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

Also, you're missing a closing quotation mark after the `url:`

```
url:'getinfo.php',  // Closed the quote
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the closing quotation mark. It's actually not missing in my live script.